# Calculating bittorent info_hash with java

Tags: java, hash, sha1, bittorrent, info-hash

I am trying to calculate the `info_hash` value for a torrent. I read the whole torrent into `StringBuffer`, then cut it like the following:

```
d8:announce...info[d6:length...e]e
```

I can't seem to get the correct hash. Does reading the torrent into a `StringBuffer` corrupt the byte string at the end? Am I missing something?

```
public void calculateInfoHash( ){
try{
    int index = rawData.indexOf("4:info") + 6;
    int end = rawData.length() - 1;

    String info = rawData.substring( index , end );

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA" );
    md.update( info.getBytes() );
    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    for ( byte b : digest ) {
    // print byte as 2 hex digits with lead 0. 
    //Separate pairs of digits with space
    //System.out.print( "%" );
    System.out.printf( "%02X", b & 0xff );
        }
    System.out.println( );

}catch( Exception e ) { 
    System.out.println( e.toString() );
}
}
```

Comment: Based on your other question, you have an answer.   I'd like to know what it was, as I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: The way i solved it was to calculate the hash as i am reading bytes from the file. If you read it in to a string and then calculate it. it never works something gets corrupted. Calculate it as you are reading the file from disk. in your decoder class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the correct algorithm in this case, but from a code perspective whenever you call getBytes() on a String you should always specify a character set, otherwise it uses the system default which often isn't what you want.  Replace it with:

```
md.update( info.getBytes("UTF-8") );
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could just grab the source code for [Azureus](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/) and see how they do it.

Comment: Hi! Your link redirects from sourceforge.net to vuze.com (Vuze Bittorrent Client which is freeware so I couldn't find any source code for that). Thanks!

Comment: Azureus was renamed Vuze many years ago. They closed the source many years ago as well.